# Crash emulator after sending sms

Tags: android, crash, sms, emulation

When I send from eclipse an eastern european chars like ö, the emulator windows disappears (crashes immediatly). Any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Via console:

telnet localhost 5554 (or your port number)

sms send number message

Comment: If the sent sms is short and my sms contains not English alphabet, it appears as a Chinese sms :(. If sms is long console shows "connection to host lost" and the emulator disappears.